# Date compression

Tags: date, compression

i got a problem in a project to uncompress a date.
(No documentation is available)

I have to convert a date, shown by this 6 Bytes:

0xFD 0x77 0x59 0x51 0x10 0x00

Did anyone know, how to uncompress ?
The date is from today, ~ 10:30 GMT

Programm language doesn´t matters.

(It is just a question of understanding. Not a question by programming)

Christian

added Again some examples

11:09 -->

```
0x fd 77 59 fd 10 00
```

11:09 -->

```
0x fd 77 79 05 28 00
```

11:05 -->

```
0x fd 77 59 fd 28 00
```

Comment: @TheNewIdiot I suspect it is little endian which would make it 70084294653, Can the OP provide another example?

Comment: @PeterLawrey You are correct , didn't come to my mind !

Comment: From the last minutes: 0x fd|77|59|fd|10|00  or 0x fd|77|59|fd|28|00

Comment: How far apart are those two last samples?

Comment: The difference between those two samples is 792576 - but that assumes it's a sequential "large number", and I'm not convinced. It may be that the first four bytes is number of seconds, and the lower part is number of ticks or tenths of a second or some such.

Comment: @MatsPetersson ~10:51 (GMT, today)

Comment: Right, so about 20 minutes apart.

Comment: How are you receiving these dates - can you write a piece of code to fetch them as quickly as possible, and see where it changes when?

Comment: @ChristianNRW, can you give multiple examples, e.g. 10 samples, each of them taken about 1 second after the previous one? that would make it much easier to figure out where the seconds reside.

Comment: Again some examples `11:09 --> 0x fd 77 59 fd 10 00
11:09 --> 0x fd 77 79 05 28 00
11:05 --> 0x fd 77 59 fd 28 00`

Comment: Please also add the examples to the question by editing it. The formatting possibilities you have there are better. BTW, are you sure these are dates? The data you provided here is sometimes identical to the examples you provided earlier, which suggests that the data is reoccurring. It can therefor not be a continually, non-recurring series (i.e. cant be a current timestamp).

Comment: Yes. i got a small document that byte 1-x are the date. Maybe as timestamp or in readable date format. There is also a Mark that describes a "normal" Dateformat (YYYYMMDDHHIISSmm) but that are 9 Bytes (2,1,1,1,1,1,2) and i don´t be able to convert the 6 Bytes to those 6 Bytes.

Comment: edit:  ..be able to convert the 6 Bytes to those 9 Bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was, to convert the Data byte array not via Java to Hex. In several cases (Byte is > 127) the result is a ..FD Hex Value. If i convert it otherwise, the Log Result is i.e.:

```
0x DD7719b33A00

dd7 -> 7dd -> 2013

7 -> 7 -> Month

19 -> 25 (dec.) --> Day

b -> 11 -> Hour

33 -> 51 -> Min.

A -> 10 -> seconds

 0 -> 0 -> ms
```